DT::datatable regular expression OR-operator problem
OR-operator works in the first case but not in the second case
This code creates DT::datatable() which returns all rows which match either "mazda" or "datsun"
library(DT)

datatable(
  mtcars, 
  filter = list(position = 'none', clear = TRUE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE, search = 'mazda|datsun'),
    pageLength = 5
  )
)

So I would expect this code to return all rows which match "good" or "ideal". But it matches only "ideal":
datatable(
  ggplot2::diamonds |> head(),
  filter = list(position = 'none', clear = TRUE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE, search = 'ideal|good'),
    pageLength = 5
  )
)

What could be wrong here?

What is in diamonds |> head()? Was it intentional? Of course ideal|good finds ideal or good and it works.

I am able to reproduce this and solve with (ideal|good) for some reason.

@WiktorStribiżew both datasets are included in standard R

Same behavior with tibble(name = stringr::fruit) and fruit|berry. It only matches fruit without parenthesis but matches fruit and berry within.

@WiktorStribiżew the DT package is not part of the tidyverse: https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

It is not about what part of what it is, OP is using tidyverse

Problem has nothing to do with tidyverse and in fact the OP does not even use any tidyverse syntax. Problem lies within DT::datatable and the clash of interests between regex and smart. Will remove the superfluous tidyverse lib call.

And BTW don't understand the downvote / close vote at all, a perfectly valid reprex with indeed a strange behaviour, which does not make sense at first sight and needs some understyanding of the underlying JavaScript library to understand the issue.

Addendum: ok diamonds is a ggplot2 dataset (thought it is in base R) - added the reference.

You need to disable the smart option (for whatever obscure reason it works for the mtcars, but as per the docs you should always disable smart when using regex):
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

datatable(
  ggplot2::diamonds |>
    group_by(cut) |>
    slice_sample(n = 2),
  filter = list(position = 'none', clear = TRUE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE, search = 'ideal|good', 
                  smart = FALSE), ## disable the smart option
    pageLength = 6
  )
)


